# Group by Day and Item Total, but Output Item Names as Keys

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've been trying these examples :  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/ and 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/

Sample documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc", "price" : 10, "quantity" : 2, "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T08:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "jkl", "price" : 20, "quantity" : 1, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 5, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:05:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "abc", "price" : 10, "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T08:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 5, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T09:05:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 6, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 5, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T12:05:10Z") }
{ "_id" : 7, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T14:12:12Z") }
```

But my need is kind of mixes of them. In push example, the results look like:

```
{
    "_id" : { "day" : 46, "year" : 2014 },
    "itemsSold" : [
        { "item" : "abc", "quantity" : 10 },
        { "item" : "xyz", "quantity" : 10 },
        { "item" : "xyz", "quantity" : 5 },
        { "item" : "xyz", "quantity" : 10 }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : { "day" : 34, "year" : 2014 },
    "itemsSold" : [
        { "item" : "jkl", "quantity" : 1 },
        { "item" : "xyz", "quantity" : 5 }
    ]
 }
 {
     "_id" : { "day" : 1, "year" : 2014 },
     "itemsSold" : [ { "item" : "abc", "quantity" : 2 } ]
 }
```

And in $addToSet example, results look like:

```
{ "_id" : { "day" : 46, "year" : 2014 }, "itemsSold" : [ "xyz", "abc" ] }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 34, "year" : 2014 }, "itemsSold" : [ "xyz", "jkl" ] }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 1, "year" : 2014 }, "itemsSold" : [ "abc" ] }
```

What I want is going to be like:

```
{ "_id" : { "day" : 46, "year" : 2014 }, "itemsSold" : { "xyz": 25, "abc": 10 } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 34, "year" : 2014 }, "itemsSold" : { "xyz": 5, "jkl": 1 ] }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 1, "year" : 2014 }, "itemsSold" : { "abc": 2 } }
```

Is this possible? If it is, any guide, direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your data you want two [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages, in order to first collect per `"item"` and then to add those item details to an array.

Depending on your MongoDB version you have available is how you process the rest. For MongoDB 3.6 ( of from 3.4.7 ) you can use [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) in order to reshape the data:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "year": { "$year": "$date" },
      "dayOfYear": { "$dayOfYear": "$date" },
      "item": "$item"
    },
    "total": { "$sum": "$quantity" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "year": "$_id.year",
      "dayOfYear": "$_id.dayOfYear"
    },
    "itemsSold": { "$push": { "k": "$_id.item", "v": "$total" } }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": -1 } },
  { "$addFields": { 
    "itemsSold": { "$arrayToObject": "$itemsSold" }
  }}
])
```

Or with earlier versions, you can simply post process the results. All the "aggregation" work is done before the last stage anyway:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "year": { "$year": "$date" },
      "dayOfYear": { "$dayOfYear": "$date" },
      "item": "$item"
    },
    "total": { "$sum": "$quantity" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "year": "$_id.year",
      "dayOfYear": "$_id.dayOfYear"
    },
    "itemsSold": { "$push": { "k": "$_id.item", "v": "$total" } }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": -1 } },
  /*
  { "$addFields": { 
    "itemsSold": { "$arrayToObject": "$itemsSold" }
  }}
  */
]).map( d => Object.assign( d, 
  { 
    itemsSold: d.itemsSold.reduce((acc,curr) =>
      Object.assign(acc, { [curr.k]: curr.v }),
      {}
    )
  }
))
```

Either way produces the same desired result:

```
{
        "_id" : {
                "year" : 2014,
                "dayOfYear" : 46
        },
        "itemsSold" : {
                "xyz" : 25,
                "abc" : 10
        }
}
{
        "_id" : {
                "year" : 2014,
                "dayOfYear" : 34
        },
        "itemsSold" : {
                "jkl" : 1,
                "xyz" : 5
        }
}
{
        "_id" : {
                "year" : 2014,
                "dayOfYear" : 1
        },
        "itemsSold" : {
                "abc" : 2
        }
}
```

So you can do things with new aggregation features, but really that end result is just "reshaping" which is usually best left to client processing instead.

Comment: What do  you mean by 'client processing?' Are you suggesting that I need to 'reshape' programatically, not in mongodb aggregation? If so, which is faster? I've at least 100k documents in collection.